# My BlackBerry 10 Simulator can't connect to wireless network?

Tags: blackberry-simulator, blackberry-10

I have a blackberry 10 simulator which I am running on VMWare Fusion, however it can't connect to the wireless networks. How can I resolve this issue? This is some image I have attached hope it helps.  http://postimage.org/image/eei1ipnnf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have any direct experience but try the following

1) Power down your VM
2) In VMWare select your VM and then click "Edit Virtual Machine Settings"
3) Select Network Adapter
4) Change from NAT to Bridge mode, which will allow the simulator to have direct access your physical network card.
5) Start the simulator again.

this page might help you out a bit 
http://rapidberry.net/installing-and-configuring-the-simulator-for-blackberry-10-and-playbook/